# How to mock an internal server error using nock in NODEJS

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, nock

I am using Nock to test a scenario in which I am testing for Internal Server Error(500). When I run my code it complains "NOCK: No Match For Request".

Here is my unit Test code below:

```
it.only('should retry requests', function (done) {
    this.timeout(30000);
    nock('url')
      .put('query', RequestData)
      .reply(500, {
        msg: 'Internal Server Error'
      });
    serviceAPI.putRequest(RequestURL, RequestData)
      .then(function () {
        done();
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        expect(error.message).equal.to('Internal Server Error');
        nock.cleanAll();
        done();
      });
  });
```

** I am not using the request module for doing rest calls, I am using the [requestretry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/requestretry) to do the requests.

Comment: try put without argument ie `nock('url') .put(). reply (500,{ msg: 'Internal Server Error' });`

Comment: @kingdynastyk I tried that but it did now work. It is still showing the same error.

Comment: check the url again and i don't understand how this test case will help you bcoz request retry module will resend the request if the status code returned is 5xx eg 500. so this test case seems pointless and you could use persist() with nock to intercept each call but again that will be an endless loop. requestretry will keep on sending the request and nock will keep on intercepting it with 500

Comment: @kingdynastyk: In my code function I have a check which would log when max attempts are made. Hence I want the requestretry to make the call '5' times and once it makes max attempts it should log it that it made max attempts and failed. And I want to test this particular condition. 

If you send reply 200 in the same unit test then it will not throw the error, but if I keep 500 as the reply then only it throws the error.Hence the URL is correct

Comment: try adding persist() to nock like nock(url).persist().put(). reply (500)

Comment: could you edit the question and post the actual url and query you are sending

Comment: @kingdynastyk : Thank you, Using .persist() worked.